# Testing config file

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, integration-testing

I'm building skme testing on my project and wanted some clarification. Right now there's a config file for my testing that acts like my web.config file containing information for the server for the testing to pass the security and work fine. This file (vstest.execution engine.x86.exe.config) sits here: c:\microsoft visual studio 12.0\common7\ide\commonextentions\microsoft\testwindow, and is accessed in the code as AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile.
Every time a user will run a test it will modify the config file dinamically for the testing to work.
This causes some troubles. Mainly I would like the testing to use the web.config file becuase its already built and is static. 
Is there a way to do this? Also, any advice on testing configuration files would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SlowCheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WillBuikMSFT.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms) to perform transformation on my Web.Config. I have config file for every environment, thats where I keep all my configuration(eg: Web.Dev.config, Web.QA.Config).

Not sure if that answers your question.